# Pipe the output of a process to a file via UNIX shell command '>'

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix, printf

I need to pipe the output of printf statements in some c code so that instead of printing the output to the terminal, it will print the output to a file.

currently, I'm trying to do that with the following code:

```
int main() {
    printf("Line 1 .. \n > output.txt");
    write(1, "Line 2 ", 7);
}
```

This produces the output:

`Line 1 .. 
Line 2  > output.txtJims-MacBook-Pro-2:Homework1 JimmyNesbitt$`

The output looks like its doing something along the lines of what I want it to do because the `Line 2` comes before the `> output.txt`. But this is being printed to the terminal and not an external file. How can I get my print statements to be written to a file instead of printed to the terminal in this way?

Comment: Do it using the shell? Or use `fprintf`.

Comment: I've been instructed to 'redirect the output to a file at the UNIX shell level with a >'

Comment: Then use it in the shell. The code should not be affected by this requirement. It should simply use standard output.

Comment: what do you mean by use it in the shell?

Comment: `$> ./yourprogram > output_file`

Comment: $>./yourprogram | more.     $>./yourprogram | grep     to pipe to other programs.